# Openstack instance not resolving Domain names

Tags: domain-name-system, linux-networking, openstack

Hi I'm someone relatively new to openstack. I setup the cloud using microstack on an Ubuntu 22.04 machine(Fresh install). I used the following to set it up.
Initially when we setup the cloud, we ran into the [invalid image identifier or unable to access requested image (HTTP 400)](https://discourse.charmhub.io/t/microstack-invalid-image-identifier-or-unable-to-access-requested-image-http-400/5643) which we solved as mentioned by jimkeon in the link.
Next we followed the normal microstack multi-node deployment instructions given [here](https://ubuntu.com/openstack/install) to setup the 2 compute nodes needed for our project. (so we have one control node and 2 compute nodes)
We created a new image on the openstack dashboard(10.20.20.1) using an ubuntu cloud server image(RAW). We setup the network such that it looks something like this:

1. The physical network is 172.16.120.0/21 with a gateway 172.16.127.150
2. The external network created automatically by openstack is 10.20.20.0/24 with gateway of 10.20.20.1
3. The virtual network(Internal network) created within openstack is 198.168.222.0/24 with gateway 198.168.222.1.

After everything we did, on the openstack dashboard, we used `sudo ufw default allow incoming`. After this step we were able to ping the internet using the ip addresses of any site. However the VM could not resolve Domain names.

I hope someone out there has some solution to this.
Things we tried:

1. We configured resolv.conf file to point to 8.8.8.8.
2. We used `ufw allow` to allow all the ports used for openstack and specifically configured the 3. DNS port 53 and port 43(for whois).
3. We used the dashboard to reconfigure DNS port in security groups.

Result: Absolutely nothing changed.